# Opening JPG under Android/data/<app.name>/files/docscan-sdk/.../documents/<number>/ not possible

Tags: file-management, media-files

With the app of my health insurance, I am able to upload bills and other data via scans / photos of the corresponding document. In order to have my own repository of transferred bills, I want to access the corresponding files. However, and regardless of the access method (Android file manager, copy to PC via USB or FTP), I cannot view the corresponding image. At the same time, all file metadata (file size, access permissions, ...) looks "promising", i.e. it has reasonable file size, R/W-access is granted, time stamps correspond to scan / upload events, opening these files with notepad results in the usual garbage you'll see when opening image data...

Actually, I only want to know how I can view this data.

The curious, but Android ignorant me would also like to understand what is happening here. What do you need to do, to have image data available for everything but viewing?

Comment: There's a possibility that the image is actually encrypted by them for safety/privacy reason so it can only be viewed on their apps. At least that's basing on my bank/insurance statement PDF that asks for the password when opened on external apps.

Comment: Thxs, @AndrewT., I did not think of this obvious reason! As I see it, your comment should be marked as answer - if it weren't a comment ;-)